# Google Analytics - Issue with sending events

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have problem with sending Google Analytics events. I'm trying to use this code:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign', {
  nonInteraction: true
});
```

to check if someone have watched video. In the header I have script with Google Analytics code but it isn't working.

I use this code:

```
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXX');
```

In 'network' I can't see sended values. What should I do?

Comment: These are two different versions of the GA code that are not compatible, so first thing would be to decide which one do you want to use. gtag is now recommended, so more future proof, but on the short term it's probably easier to get support for ga() (analytics.js) since at the moment there is not all that much experience with gtag.

Comment: That was the knowledge I havent'. Thank you very much! Now everything is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With global site tag you'll have to switch to `gtag()` command instead of `ga()` to send data to Analytics.
in your case there should be something like

```
gtag('event', 'play', {
  'event_category': 'Videos',
  'event_label': 'Fall Campaign',
  'non_interaction': true
});
```

here are the docs on migrating `analytics/ga` to `gtag`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration#track_events

Comment: It' s working! Thank you very much. I didn' t know there' s a difference so I have to read more about these. Thx once again!